# PostgreSQL - Column name of a table is the name of a function

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table in my database where on of the column names is called "end". End is a timestamp.

When I try to run a simple query such as:

```
select end
from driver_shift_log
```

I get a syntax error because it is interpreting end not as a column name, but as a SQL function. Any tips on the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select "end"
from driver_shift_log
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/113ac/1/0)